# Anyone up for a 3x3x3 Hidato?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, three-dimensional

So, I have been pretty evil with how I make Hidato puzzles lately, with there being no numbers. To make up for it, I have decided to make a 3x3x3 Hidato for you all. Yes you read that right. I made a Hidato puzzle to apologize for my evil Hidato puzzles. So, I hope you enjoy this one!

The puzzle:

1st layer:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | $\color{white}.$ |
| 18 |  |  |
| 6 | 16 |  |

2nd layer:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | $\color{white}.$ | 21 |
| 7 |  | 12 |
| 5 |  |  |

3rd layer:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 |  | 23 |
|  | 27 |  |
| $\color{white}.$ |  |  |

GL HF! (Good Luck Have Fun!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

> ```
>  1  2 13
> 18 17 14
>  6 16 15
>
> 19 20 21
>  7  3 12
>  5  4 11
>
> 25 24 23
> 26 27 22
>  8  9 10
> ```

Multiple solutions are possible:

> In the solution shown above, 3 and 17 can be swapped, or 4 and 9 can be swapped.
>  In either case 10 and 11 can also be swapped, as well as 20 and 24.
>  This gives a total of 12 solutions.

Comment: lol good job! Also sorry for there being multiple solutions, but still, good job!